# Questions will function swipe keyboard for Android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, swipe

I'm having trouble with the swipe functionality on a Android keyboard.

I wonder if that is a feature of the soft keyboard comes to swipe of

```
android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView $ OnKeyboardActionListener
```

I implement this swipe function but when I come to actually use it, the swipe function is too slow and is not well recognized.

How can I improve the swipe feature  to work well? Alternately, how do you adjust the speed or distance of the swipe function?

Comment: If you are creating your own swipe function on keyboard look at Gabe's answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000937/how-to-make-swipe-keyboard-like-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39200117/1293492